# Is there a way to instantiate a class via Expression.New where 'ConstructorInfo' is supplied by an ExpressionParameter?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-expressions

I would like to instantiate a (non-generic) class in C# (`ClassToBeInstantiated`) that has a public *non*-parameterless constructor via LINQ `Expression.New` inside an `Expression.Block`.

*see update below, based on answer from @sweeper*

#### Description

According to the documentation, the only overloads for `Expression.New` that do accept arguments require a `ConstructorInfo` argument. As I do not have access to that info beforehand, but have to retrieve this inside the `Expression.Block`.
So I am able to use an `Expression.Call` on the `type` `ClassToBeInstantiated` that is passed into the block.

However, all `Expression.New` overloads only accept either `ConstructorInfo` as an argument or for an instantiation if I want to pass arguments to the constructor. `Type` is only available for using a *parameterless* constructor.

I cannot use a `ParameterExpression` holding a `ConstructorInfo` either.

#### Question

So my question: is there a way around this with `Expression.New`? I know I can use `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` via another `Expression.Call`. But this seems akward to me, as -at least in my opinion- the `Expression.New` API should exactly do this for me.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help, comments and reply.

#### The class to be instantiated

Here is some additional information to further illustrate the case:

```cs
public class ClassToBeInstantiated
{
  public ClassToBeInstantiated(int count) { }
}
```

#### Helper class to retrieve ConstructorInfo

```cs
public static class GetConstructor
{
  public static ConstructorInfo GetNonGenericConstructorInfo(Type type, params Type[] typeArguments) =>
    type.GetConstructor(typeArguments);
}
```

```cs
[Test]
public void InstantiateTypeViaExpressionNew()
{
  var typeExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type), "type");
  var countExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "count");
  var ctorExpression = Expression.Variable(typeof(ConstructorInfo), "constructorInfo");
  var block = Expression.Block
  (
    new[] { ctorExpression },
    Expression.Assign(ctorExpression, Expression.Call(typeof(GetConstructor), nameof(GetConstructor.GetNonGenericConstructorInfo),
      Type.EmptyTypes, typeExpression, Expression.Constant(new[] { countExpression.Type }))),
    Expression.New(/* error - obviously does not compile: ctorInfo */, countExpression)
  );

  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, int, object>>(block, typeExpression, countExpression);
  var func = lambda.Compile();
  var o = func.Invoke(typeof(ClassToBeInstantiated), 4);
  var instance = o as ClassToBeInstantiated;
  Assert.NotNull(instance);
}
```

#### Update with `Expression.Call` instead of `Expression.New`

I updated the code example from my original question, based on the answer from @Sweeper to provide a full example (in case someone is interested):

##### Updated helper class

Here, I added the field `constructorInfoInvokeMethodInfo` for retrieval of the `MethodInfo` for the `ConstructorInfo.Invoke()` method (to be called from inside the `Expression.Block`:

```cs
public static class GetConstructor
{
  public static ConstructorInfo GetNonGenericConstructorInfo(Type type, params Type[] typeArguments) =>
    type.GetConstructor(typeArguments);

  public static readonly MethodInfo constructorInfoInvokeMethodInfo =
    typeof(ConstructorInfo).GetMethod(nameof(ConstructorInfo.Invoke), new[] { typeof(object[]) });
}
```

##### Updated test for Expression.Block

Here, I replaced the (non-working) `Expression.New` with an `Expression.Call` to instantiate the type via `ConstructorInfo.Invoke()`:

```cs
[Test]
public void InstantiateTypeViaExpressionCall()
{
  var typeExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type), "type");
  var countExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "count");
  var ctorExpression = Expression.Variable(typeof(ConstructorInfo), "constructorInfo");
var block = Expression.Block
(
  new[] { ctorExpression },
  Expression.Assign
  (
    ctorExpression,
    Expression.Call(typeof(Activator), nameof(GetNonGenericConstructorInfo), Type.EmptyTypes, typeExpression, Expression.Constant(new[] { countExpression.Type }))
  ),
  Expression.Call(ctorExpression, constructorInfoInvokeMethodInfo, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), Expression.Convert(countExpression, typeof(object))))
);

  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, int, object>>(block, typeExpression, countExpression);
  var func = lambda.Compile();
  var o = func.Invoke(typeof(ClassToBeInstantiated), 4);
  var instance = o as ClassToBeInstantiated;
  Assert.NotNull(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question: is there a way around this with `Expression.New`? I know I can use `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` via another `Expression.Call`.

This is exactly what you should do.

Think about the expression tree that you want to create. Since the final usage that you want to achieve looks like:

```
func.Invoke(typeof(ClassToBeInstantiated), 4);
```

`func`'s expression must look like:

```
(type, count) => GetConstructor.GetNonGenericConstructorInfo(type, typeof(int)).Invoke(new object[] {count})
```

This seems to be what you were trying to do too, just with an extra local variable.

It *cannot* be:

```
(type, count) => new type(count)
```

Because `new type(count)` is not a valid expression. `type` is just a parameter.

This has nothing to do with `new` expressions that `Expression.New` creates. There are no `NewExpression`s in your desired expression at all. It would be *very weird* if `Expression.New` suddenly starts inserting `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` calls in the expression tree, because that is *not* what it is supposed to create at all.

You *could* use `Expression.New` here to create expressions such as:

```
(type, count) => new ClassToBeInstantiated(count)
```

But I don't think that's what you want... You want the `type` parameter to determine what type to instantiate, and assume that a one-parameter `int` constructor to be available, right?

Using sharplab.io, you can write the lambda expression you want, and see what code the compiler actually generates for building the expression tree. After cleaning up the code that generates for

```
Expression<Func<Type, int, object>> func =
        (type, count) => GetConstructor.GetNonGenericConstructorInfo(type, typeof(int)).Invoke(new object[] {count});
```

You get:

```
MethodInfo getConstructorMethod = typeof(GetConstructor).GetMethod(nameof(GetConstructor.GetNonGenericConstructorInfo));
MethodInfo invokeMethod = typeof(ConstructorInfo).GetMethod(nameof(ConstructorInfo.Invoke), new Type[] { typeof(object[]) });

ParameterExpression typeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type), "type");
ParameterExpression countParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "count");

// GetNonGenericConstructorInfo(type, typeof(int))
MethodCallExpression instance = Expression.Call(null, getConstructorMethod,
    typeParam, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(Type), Expression.Constant(typeof(int), typeof(Type)))
);
// // .Invoke(new object[] { count })
MethodCallExpression body = Expression.Call(instance, invokeMethod,
    Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), Expression.Convert(countParam, typeof(object)))
);
Expression<Func<Type, int, object>> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, int, object>>(body, typeParam, countParam);
```

And `func.Compile()(typeof(ClassToBeInstantiated), 4) as ClassToBeInstantiated` is not null.

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation! I updated my example according to it.